# std::async is causing segmentation fault (or slow)

Tags: c++, linux, g++, stdasync

i have written simple class to solve system of linear equations , to  parallelize the matrix row subtractions i used std::async . after size of 10x10 matrix the program is crashing due to segmentation fault.
my first implementation was to replace  `vecSub((mat[c]), (temp));` with just `std::async(std::launch::async, vecSub, std::ref(mat[c]), std::ref(temp))` but then discovered that if we don't assign it to any variable destructor is called and .get() is called , and stops the main thread (which was the reason it slowed down), so i changed it to the below implementation and now i am getting seg fault
**this is single threaded:**

```
class solver
{
    Mat mat;

public:
    //give eqn in the form ax1+ax2+ax3..axN = k (coeffiants only)
    Vec solve(Mat &in)
    {

        mat = in;

        ge(mat);
        return (bs(mat));
    }
    Vec solve(Mat &&in)
    {
        mat = std::move(in);
        ge(mat);
        return (bs(mat));
    }

private:
    void ge(Mat &mat)
    {

        using li = long int;

        for (li p = 0; p < mat[0].size() - 1; p++)
        {
            for (li c = p + 1; c < mat.size(); c++)
            {
                auto x = mat[c][p] / mat[p][p];
                auto temp = mat[p];
                vecMul(x, temp);
                vecSub((mat[c]), (temp));
    
            }
        }
    }
    Vec bs(Mat &mat)
    {
        using li = long int;
        Vec x(mat.size());
        for (li i = mat.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            double s = 0;
            for (li j = i; j < mat[0].size() - 1; j++)
            {
                s += mat[i][j] * x[j];
                x[i] = ((mat[i][mat[0].size() - 1] - s) / (mat[i][i]));
            }
        }
        return x;
    }
    static void vecMul(double a, Vec &b)
    {
        using li = size_t;
        for (li i = 0; i < b.size(); i++)
            b[i] *= a;
    }
    //static
    static void vecAdd(Vec &a, Vec &b)
    {
        using li = size_t;
        assert(a.size() == b.size());
        for (li i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
            a[i] = a[i] + b[i];
    }
    static void vecSub(Vec &a, Vec &b)
    {
        using li = size_t;
        assert(a.size() == b.size());
        for (li i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
            a[i] = a[i] - b[i];
    }
};
```

**multithreaded**

```
class solver
{
    Mat mat;

public:
    //give eqn in the form ax1+ax2+ax3..axN = k (coeffiants only)
    Vec solve(Mat &in)
    {

        mat = in;

        ge(mat);
        return (bs(mat));
    }
    Vec solve(Mat &&in)
    {
        mat = std::move(in);
        ge(mat);
        return (bs(mat));
    }

private:
    void ge(Mat &mat)
    {

        using li = long int;

        for (li p = 0; p < mat[0].size() - 1; p++)
        {
            std::vector<std::future<void>> ts;

            for (li c = p + 1; c < mat.size(); c++)
            {
                auto x = mat[c][p] / mat[p][p];
                auto temp = mat[p];
                vecMul(x, temp);
                ts.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, vecSub, std::ref(mat[c]), std::ref(temp)));
            }
            for (auto &t : ts)
            {

                t.get();
            }
        }
    }
    Vec bs(Mat &mat)
    {
        using li = long int;
        Vec x(mat.size());
        for (li i = mat.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            double s = 0;
            for (li j = i; j < mat[0].size() - 1; j++)
            {
                s += mat[i][j] * x[j];
                x[i] = ((mat[i][mat[0].size() - 1] - s) / (mat[i][i]));
            }
        }
        return x;
    }
    static void vecMul(double a, Vec &b)
    {
        using li = size_t;
        for (li i = 0; i < b.size(); i++)
            b[i] *= a;
    }
    //static
    static void vecAdd(Vec &a, Vec &b)
    {
        using li = size_t;
        assert(a.size() == b.size());
        for (li i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
            a[i] = a[i] + b[i];
    }
    static void vecSub(Vec &a, Vec &b)
    {
        using li = size_t;
        // assert(a.size() == b.size());
        for (li i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
            a[i] = a[i] - b[i];
    }
};
```

the segmentation is occuring at

```
static void vecSub(Vec &a, Vec &b)
    {
        using li = size_t;
        assert(a.size() == b.size());
        for (li i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
            a[i] = a[i] - b[i];
    }
```

[image: when using std::async]

[image: multithreaded]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever the `Mat` type is, I'm pretty sure this:

```
auto temp = mat[p];
```

does not create a reference but a copy. It means this

```
ts.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, vecSub, std::ref(mat[c]), std::ref(temp)));`
```

actually makes a reference to a temporary value `temp` which is about to be destroyed at the end of this loop. That's undefined behavior.
This could possibly fix the issue:

```
auto& temp = mat[p];
```

Comment: That's why the issue didn't occur when it was runn sequencially but like u told it would go out of scope when its running asynchronously

Comment: hey main you solution doesnt work because vecMul() modifies the original matrix , whiich will give garbage values , any other idea??

Comment: does it still crash?

Comment: its not crashing and i cant use a reference since it'll change the original matrix . it has no bugs but the async version is much slower ,[here is the updated problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66667664/stdasync-is-very-slow)

Comment: If it no longer crashes (which was the original issue) then mark it as [solved], since you already made a new post for your new issues.